# Rails/Heroku undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have problem with one of my model. When I pushed it to heroku I get error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `parent_id' for #<Kategorie:0x007f607f8a3ea0>):
```

When I run my app in localhost there is no problem. I've tried to run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:migrate:status --app app_name
heroku restart
```

but nothing work for me.

Update:

When I check status everything is ok. Kategories table is empty, but everything work on local server.

In my model I have:

```
has_many :children, class_name: "Kategorie", foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

Comment: whats the status? All migrations are up?

Comment: Is there any data in `Kategories` table ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there some code in your model or controller that calls **parent_id** and is parent while parent_id is not part of your table columns? If you check the heroku rails console: Can you see the table having all your desired columns? May be there is a migration missing or you call the method parent_id and it is not part of your migrations?